# ScrollTop - Chatbot

Tags: javascript, chatbot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyttH.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wekz.jpg)

i am newbie in JS. I am working on chatbot and I forked this code https://github.com/arjuntherajeev/chatbot_template/

the chat window is HTML/JS

I am having the issue with the scrolling after certain amount of questions, is like the scroll will get stuck instead of flowing correctly and showing the question/answer.

I can keep asking stuff in the chat window but the scroll bar doesnt follow.

I think it has something to do with the scroll top property.
any help is highly appreciated!

this is the JS

```
$(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");

function newMessage() {
    message = $(".message-input input").val();
    if ($.trim(message) == '') {
        return false;
    }
    $('<li class="sent"><img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/mikeross.png" alt="" /><p>' + message + '</p></li>').appendTo($('.messages ul'));
    $('.message-input input').val(null);
    $('.contact.active .preview').html('<span>You: </span>' + message);
    $(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
    $.ajax({
    url: "/send_message/"+message,
    //data: {'messag':messag,'context':context}
}).done(function(e) {
    newReply(e);
});
};

function newReply(message) {
    if ($.trim(message) == '') {
        return false;
    }
    $('<li class="replies"><img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/harveyspecter.png" alt="" /><p>' + message + '</p></li>').appendTo($('.messages ul'));
    $('.message-input input').val(null);
    $('.contact.active .preview').html('<span>You: </span>' + message);
    $(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
};

$('.submit').click(function () {
    newMessage();
    newReply();
});

$(window).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        newMessage();
        newReply();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, I would assume $(document).height() would not grow with the chats and stay the same. Have you checked that?

Comment: thanks @Hozikimaru. you mean the top statement in the code?. I need the chat to continue to scroll as long as there is replies and answers. I am newbie in JS, so I am not sure on your question. thx

Comment: I added an image to the original question, so you can see the issue. thanks!

Comment: that still does not answer the question. It could have scrolled exactly the amount of document. Per my comment, check the height() property and see if it actually increases.

Comment: You are right, it is not growing. it remains 987 all the time. I have attached the pic. how this be fixed? Could u give me a tip? thanks

Comment: You would need to inspect the element that actually is growing. By document, you are referring to the whole dom, not the chat window that is growing. You can right click and inspect element in chrome so should be something like $('.chatWindow').height();